# Correct way to use custom weight maps in unet architecture

Tags: python, pytorch, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

There is a famous trick in u-net architecture to use custom weight maps to increase accuracy. Below are the details of it:

[image]

Now, by asking here and at multiple other place, I get to know about 2 approaches. I want to know which one is correct or is there any other right approach which is more correct?

1. First is to use `torch.nn.Functional` method in the training loop:

   `loss = torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(output, target, w)` where w will be the calculated custom weight.
2. Second is to use `reduction='none'` in the calling of loss function outside the training loop
   `criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropy(reduction='none')`

   and then in the training loop multiplying with the custom weight:

   ```
   gt # Ground truth, format torch.long
   pd # Network output
   W # per-element weighting based on the distance map from UNet
   loss = criterion(pd, gt)
   loss = W*loss # Ensure that weights are scaled appropriately
   loss = torch.sum(loss.flatten(start_dim=1), axis=0) # Sums the loss per image
   loss = torch.mean(loss) # Average across a batch
   ```

Now, I am kinda confused which one is right or is there any other way, or both are right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The weighting portion looks like just simply weighted cross entropy which is performed like this for the number of classes (2 in the example below).

```
weights = torch.FloatTensor([.3, .7])
loss_func = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=weights)
```

EDIT:

Have you seen [this implementation](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/weighted-pixelwise-nllloss2d/7766?u=jchaykow) from Patrick Black?

```
# Set properties
batch_size = 10
out_channels = 2
W = 10
H = 10

# Initialize logits etc. with random
logits = torch.FloatTensor(batch_size, out_channels, H, W).normal_()
target = torch.LongTensor(batch_size, H, W).random_(0, out_channels)
weights = torch.FloatTensor(batch_size, 1, H, W).random_(1, 3)

# Calculate log probabilities
logp = F.log_softmax(logits)

# Gather log probabilities with respect to target
logp = logp.gather(1, target.view(batch_size, 1, H, W))

# Multiply with weights
weighted_logp = (logp * weights).view(batch_size, -1)

# Rescale so that loss is in approx. same interval
weighted_loss = weighted_logp.sum(1) / weights.view(batch_size, -1).sum(1)

# Average over mini-batch
weighted_loss = -1. * weighted_loss.mean()
```

Comment: The thing is weight is calculated by a certain function here and is not discreet .for more information, here is a paper - https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597

Comment: @Mark oh I see now. So it is a pixelwise loss output. And the borders are pre-computed using some library like `opencv` or something, and then those pixel positions are saved for each image and then multiplied by the loss tensors later on during training so that the algorithm focuses on reducing loss in those areas.

Comment: Thanks.this legit looks like an answer,I'll try verifying and implementing it more and will accept your answer after it.

Comment: Can you explain the intuition behind this line `logp = logp.gather(1, target.view(batch_size, 1, H, W))`

Answer (score 0):

Note that torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss() is a class that calls torch.nn.functional. 
See https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/loss.html#CrossEntropyLoss

You can use the weights when you define the criteria. Comparing them functionally, both methods are the same.

Now, I do not understand your idea of computing loss inside the training loop in method 1 and outside the training loop in method 2. if you compute loss outside the loop then how will you backpropagate?

Comment: I was not confused between using `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss() ` and `torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(output, target, w)`, I was confused how to use custom weight maps in the loss.Please see this paper - https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597 and let me know, if you are still not able to figure out what I am asking

Comment: If I understand it correctly, I think method 2 is the right one. The weights (w) inside the loss torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(output, target, w) are weights for classes not w(x) in the formula. We can easily test it with a small script.

Comment: Yep, even I am reaching to the same conclusion.I'll revert to you back if my network runs as expected and will mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: okay, its not working.I am getting `grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs` when I run loss = loss*w method

Comment: Are you sure you are summing them up or taking the mean?